# How to modify date when copying using a macro?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, number-formatting

I am writing a macro in VBA. I have a loop that goes through a list of dates and every entry where the minute is `00,15.30.45` it copies the date and time into a new column. This is only part of the code I am working on so that is why it seems pointless at the moment. My trouble is I need to modify the time that is copied into the new column. I need the date to stay the same but the time must be modified so that:

```
hh:00 becomes   hh-1:45
hh:15 becomes   hh  :00
hh:30 becomes   hh  :15
hh:45 becomes   hh  :30
```

I have below the current code that I have and everything works except obviously it does not modify the time because I just made that up to make sense of what I want to do. What code do I need to modify the hour and minute? Thanks!

```
Dim X As Integer

Range("A2").Select
NumRows = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
Range("A2").Select

For X = 2 To NumRows
    If (Minute(ActiveCell.Value) = 0) Then
        Range("D2").Value = ActiveCell.Value
        Range("D2").NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD HH-1:45"
    ElseIf (Minute(ActiveCell.Value) = 15) Then
        Range("D2").Value = ActiveCell.Value
        Range("D2").NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:00"        
    ElseIf (Minute(ActiveCell.Value) = 30) Then
        Range("D2").Value = ActiveCell.Value
        Range("D2").NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:15" 
    ElseIf (Minute(ActiveCell.Value) = 45) Then
        Range("D2").Value = ActiveCell.Value
        Range("D2").NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:30"
    End If

    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next X
```

Comment: Are all the times going to be on the quarter hour?  If so, just subtract 15 minutes from each time value.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld That is what I want to do is just subtract 15 minutes from each value but that is what I need help with.

Comment: Just use  `Range("D2").Value = dateadd("s",-15,Range("D2").value)`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thank you for this! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm at a bar-b-que ([Happy 4th of JULY EVERYONE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1weRo8uWA0)) and this seems way more interesting than the guests that are here.

So to add time like you know inutes, you should probably use the [TimeSerial Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timeserial-function). I tried to modify your code to do what you said, but truthfully it's hard during a bar-b-Q.

A couple suggestions.

1. [Don't use select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)
2. [Don't use Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26409117/why-use-integer-instead-of-long/51689021#51689021)
3. To add 4 hours 3 minutes and 8 seconds to a date.... `TimeSerial(4, 3, 8)`

Here's how I tried to change your code to get what you want. You should be able to extrapolate what I meant.

```
Sub Running_From_That_Water_Like_My_Name_Was_TedKennedy()

Dim X As Long, WSheet As Worksheet, increaseAMOUNT As Double


Set WSheet = ActiveSheet '<---- make sure this is correct

With WSheet


Dim aCell As Range: Set aCell = .Range("A2")
Dim increaseAMOUNT As Double: increaseAMOUNT = TimeSerial(0, 15, 0) 'this adds `15 minutes



For X = 2 To Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count


    If (Minute(ActiveCell.Value) = 0) Then

    Range("D2").Value = aCell.Value + increaseAMOUNT '<----you can modify the amount to increase consistently or include your own TimeSerial
    Range("D2").NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD HH-1:45"


    ElseIf (Minute(aCell.Value) = 15) Then
    Range("D2").Value = aCell.Value + increaseAMOUNT
    Range("D2").NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:00"

    ElseIf (Minute(aCell.Value) = 30) Then
   Range("D2").Value = aCell.Value + increaseAMOUNT
    Range("D2").NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:15"

    ElseIf (Minute(aCell.Value) = 45) Then
    Range("D2").Value = aCell.Value + increaseAMOUNT
    Range("D2").NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:30"


    End If



    Set aCell = aCell.Offset(1, 0)

    Next X
End With


End Sub
'People-I-know.Girls.Count = 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am new to this hence the very basic errors. It may take me some time to decipher everything but I appreciate the help! BTW most fun I've ever had reading an answer haha enjoy the BBQ!